# How does a void function in C works with pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create a void function in C programming that works with pointers. I have created the following functions that works with pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function_1(int *num1, int *num2) {

    int *total;

    *total = *num1 / *num2;
    return *total;
}

int main(void) {

    int numerator;
    int denominator;
    int finalAnswer;

    printf("Numerator: ");
    scanf("%d", &numerator);

    printf("Denominator: ");
    scanf("%d", &denominator);

    finalAnswer = numerator / denominator;
    printf("%d / %d = %d \n", numerator,denominator,finalAnswer);
}
```

There is no problem with this program, but when I change the first line after

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

to this : `void function_1(int *num1, int *num2) {` 
I get the following error when I try to compile my code :

```
prog1.c: In function ‘function_1’:
prog1.c:7:2: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
```

Sorry if I am doing something silly, but I have no idea what is wrong when I change int to void. I know void means nothing, but I want my code to return with void. Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Remove the `return *total;` line, optionally replace with just `return;`. If you want your function to return nothing you need to actually `return` nothing...

Comment: `int *total` is not initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing several things wrong, and apparently confusing yourself with some concepts.

1. A function declared as `void f()` can't return a value. That has nothing to do with pointers. When you change your function to "return `void`", you can't use `return value;` inside the function (or more accurately, whatever value your return will not go anywhere, which is why you have a compile-time warning).
2. If you define a variable to be a pointer type, you need to assign a valid memory address to it before using that address. `int *total` is never assigned any address and using it (`*total = *num1 / *num2;`) is dangerous and creates undefined behavior.
3. You don't need `total` to be a pointer type at all. Just do:

   ```
   int function_1(int *num1, int *num2) {
       int total;

       total = *num1 / *num2;
       return total;
   }
   ```
4. You're not using `function_1` anywhere, so all the above is irrelevant :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the Line:  return *total;
You do not return values in void functions.

Answer (score 0):

void return type means you can't return anything . remove `return *total;` from the function to allow compilation

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write your function like this -

```
void function_1(int *num1, int *num2,int *total){ //void function does not return anything 
     *total = *num1 / *num2;   
  }
```

And in `main` call it like this -

```
 function_1( &numerator, &denominator, &finalAnswer);
```

And then print the values .

[Check link to see working code.](https://ideone.com/4PAe2T)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, a function with a `void` return type can't return anything.  So you need to either remove the line `return *total;` or just call `return;`.

There's another issue here, however:

```
int *total;

*total = *num1 / *num2;
```

You declare `total` to be a pointer to an `int`, but you never assign a value to that pointer.  You then attempt to dereference the uninitialized pointer, which causes undefined behavior.

You don't really need pointers for the parameters or the return value, so if you want to return an `int` you would do this:

```
int function_1(int num1, int num2) {

    int total;

    total = num1 / num2;
    return total;
}
```

If you instead want the function to have a `void` return type and send the value back in a parameter, you'd do this:

```
void function_1(int num1, int num2, int *total) 
{
    *total = num1 / num2;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
function_1(numerator, denominator, &finalAnswer);
```