# Error: Void value not ignored as it ought to be in C programming

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing  a C program which has two functions. One function is the usual main function and the other is a pointer void function. When I try to compile my program in a Linux based system I get the following error:

```
host1@matrix:~/cprog/practice> gcc -o function1 function1.c
prog1.c: In function ‘main’:
prog1.c:16:14: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void function_1(int *num1, int *num2);

int main(void) {

    int numerator;
    int denominator;
    int finalAnswer;

    printf("Numerator: ");
    scanf("%d", &numerator);

    printf("Denominator: ");
    scanf("%d", &denominator);

    finalAnswer = function_1(&numerator, &denominator);
    printf("%d / %d = %d \n", numerator,denominator,&finalAnswer);

    return 0;
}

void function_1(int *num1, int *num2) {

    int total;

    total = *num1 / *num2;

    return;
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You *do* know the meaning of the `void` "type"?

Comment: There's also some other weird things in your code, like why are you passing the values to the function using pointers? Is there a special reason you do that? Also, in your `printf` call you attempt to print the *address* of the `finalAnswer` variable, not its value.

Comment: void means nothing. I returns nothing, but I am not returning anything. Even if I comment out the return command I still get the same error.

Comment: That's right, the function doesn't return anything, so what do you expect to happen when you assign this "nothing" to `finalAnswer`? I think you need to think about what the function you call is actually supposed to do, because it doesn't make sense it should not return anything.

Comment: You in the same class as @Batool?

Comment: @MartinJames what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243014/how-does-a-void-function-in-c-works-with-pointers), a `void` function returns nothing, so you can't assign its return value to anything.  That's why you're getting the error.

If you want the function to send back a value but have a `void` return type, define it like this:

```
void function_1(int num1, int num2, int *total) 
{
    *total = num1 / num2;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
function_1(numerator, denominator, &finalAnswer);
```

Also, your final `printf` should be this:

```
printf("%d / %d = %d \n", numerator,denominator,finalAnswer);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error. Is there a way I can have num1 and num2 both pointers. I want both of them to be pointers. When I removed void and changed it with int it worked, meaning there is something wrong I am doing with void.

Comment: Unless you plan on changing `num1` and `num2` inside of your function, there's no reason to pass them as pointers.  You can have them as pointers, but there's no apparent reason for it.  In the example I gave, `total` is a pointer because it changes a variable in the calling function by dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: "I want both of them to be pointers." because .... you just like the look of those nice little stars? --- "When I removed void and changed it with int it worked, meaning there is something wrong I am doing with void." ... yes, you expect it ("nothing") to be a value.

Comment: For clarification: The `void` type does not mean "untyped value", it means "there isn't anything here". A function declared as type `void` is a function that _does not have a return value at all_. Trying to use the return value of such a function is therefore a wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
void function_1(int *num1, int *num2)
```

returns nothing. `void` is kind of a "nothing" type, in an expression, it means to ignore the result, as a return type, it means nothing is returned. Assigning the (non-existent) return value of a `void` function doesn't make sense.